# JScript bind link to key

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, hyperlink

`<li id="add-this" style=""><a href="#">Add this</a></li>`

We all know what this does, it activates a script when you press it, but i was wondering if its possible to bind it to a key so when you hit the key it will activate the script. Tried diffent things and searched Google for a few hours now but cant find what im looking for. Im trying to make a script for my site so you can browse it with you keyboard, i can bind a script to a key but got no idea how to do it do this.

Thanks
//Nemx

Comment: Just add `keypress` or `keydown` handler to the document. PS: may worth trying to use https://github.com/tzuryby/jquery.hotkeys or to read its code

Comment: i can add a keydown, but the problem is that i cant get it to click the link, 

`(function(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        if( e.which == 68) {
            >Dont know what to put here to make it work<
        } 
    }, false);
})();`

Tried some things, `$("add-this").click(); and document.getElementById('add-this').onclick` but get the same error in the console when running them: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of nul"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an keydown, keypress or keyup event-handler to the document and trigger a click on your link. Like this (just replace *YOUR_KEYCODE* with the code from the key you want the user has to press):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if( e.which === YOUR_KEYCODE ) {
        $("#add-this").click();
    }
});
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/QEk33/

Comment: Added that but it only returns with an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null", any idea why?

Comment: @Nemx are you shure that you've replaced YOUR_KEYCODE with a keycode? Here you can get the keycode you need http://jsbin.com/uyorip/2/quiet

Comment: Well yeah ofcourse I have replaced it, 68 = D. Thats not the problem, its when i press the key i get the error.

Comment: @nemx which browser do you use?

Comment: Yeah it works just fine, just tried it on another site. Trying to figure out why it doesnt work, anyways ty for your help =)

Comment: @nemx Ok, if you stuck on another problem don't be shy and come back :) and btw, if your question is answered, mark it as it is ;)